# Download pdf in the mobile version of the application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf

When you click on the button, the pdf file should download to the phone. In chrome, he downloads without problems. How can I implement a file download in a mobile application?

```
<q-btn class="button blue-btn" @click="getPDF">Download</q-btn>
```

```
getPDF: function () {
      html2canvas(document.querySelector('#ticket'))
        .then((canvas) => {
          let doc = new JSPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4')
          doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL(''), 'JPG', 0, 0, 300, 250)
          let fileName = ` ${moment(this.readings.date).format('DD MM YYYY')}.pdf`
          doc.save(fileName)
        })
        .then(async () => {
          let email = this.getEmail.email
          console.log('my em:', email)
          this.$store.dispatch('send-pdf/create', { query: { email: email } })
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log('errrrror:', e)
        })
    },
```

Comment: What did make you think this should differ for mobile app?

Comment: in the mobile version it does not work

Comment: 'Mobile' can be countless devices and there can be countless reasons for the app to not work. The question is too broad and cannot be answered. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .